# Beamer - Modifying the headline

Tags: beamer, rules

With `beamer`, I use the theme `Montpellier`, *a sober theme giving basic navigational hints*.

```
\usetheme{Montpellier}                 
\useinnertheme{default}
\useoutertheme{default}
\usecolortheme{default}             
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

[image: Exampe]

I would like to reduce the width of the separation lines. Can you help me to perform that task?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX. Note that you can use backticks `\`` to mark inline code as well as package names.  It's not necessary to begin your question with a greeting or have a closing line.

Comment: You are aware, I am sure, that your proof is incorrect? q+1 does not need to be prime, however it is not divisible by any known primes, and thus only divisible by unknown primes.

Comment: @Mikael Vejdemo-Johansson: Oh, actually, this is not my proof. The picture comes from a user guide and I have chosen it to illustrate the theme. 
But since q+1 is larger than 1 it is divisible by some prime k (Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic). This prime k must be one the primes that is less than or equal to p, by our assumption that p is the largest prime. So k divides the q. Finally, since k divides both q+1 and q, it also divides 1, which is impossible. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a great expert with Beamer but I think you need to change the lines  in the file : beamerouterthemetree.sty

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
\end{beamercolorbox} 
 ...
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

You can replace 1.5 pt by 0.8pt. A safe method is to copy this file inside the work folder or inside your texmf folder.
Perhaps there is a setup macro in beamer to modify these values.